# Postgres XC Error while distributing data by replication in psql

Tags: postgresql, cluster-computing, replication, postgres-xc

I have installed, configured my Postgres XC 1.0.2 on Ubuntu. I was able to setup the GTM, Coordinator, nodes 1 & 2 with no challenges. But when attempting to distribute the data amongst the two nodes, I'm getting the below errors which are actually contradicting each other.

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE DIST_REP(T INT) DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION TO NODE datanode1,datanode2;
  ERROR:  relation "dist_rep" already exists 

postgres=# INSERT INTO DIST_REP VALUES(GENERATE_SERIES(1,100)); 
  ERROR:  relation "dist_rep" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, this seemed to be recurring most of the times when I try to create a table and insert data in Postgres-XC. I tried restarting the Coordinator, seemed to work sometimes, not promising though. Just a workaround and it was also impossible to drop the table here. Here's the command for stopping and restarting the Coordinator.

**To stop:**

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl stop -D /data_local/pgxc/data_coord1/ -Z coordinator -l /tmp/logfile_cord -mf
```

**To start:**

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data_local/pgxc/data_coord1 -Z coordinator -l /tmp/logfile_cord
```

***Note***: */usr/local/pgsql/bin* was my PostgreSQL location and */data_local/pgxc* was my Postgres-XC location.